# What is the React pattern where the children prop accepts a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to find the name of the React pattern where a component's `children` prop accepts a function, allowing a component to pass data to arbitrary children.

Here's an example of this pattern from Formik's [docs](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#children-reactreactnode--props-formikpropsvalues--reactnode):

```
<Formik>
  {({ handleSubmit, handleChange, handleBlur, values, errors }) => (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={handleChange}
        onBlur={handleBlur}
        value={values.name}
        name="name"
      />
      {errors.name &&
        <div>
          {errors.name}
        </div>}
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  )}
</Formik>
```

I tried searching for descriptions of this pattern, but was not able to find anything.

Does this pattern have a name? Are there good uses for it? Is it an anti-pattern?

Comment: https://reactpatterns.js.org/docs/function-as-child-component/

Comment: [This guy](https://americanexpress.io/faccs-are-an-antipattern/) thinks its an anti pattern. I think he makes a reasonable argument about naming being important and it could’ve just been a named renderProp. In practice, as you can see, it doesn’t really matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is directly in the documentation of Formik (https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#formik-render-methods-and-props)

> is a component that helps you with building forms. It uses a render props pattern made popular by libraries like React Motion and React Router.

You can find some more information here: https://www.patterns.dev/posts/render-props-pattern (look for "Children as a function")